# How can I sort my array in descending order in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
mutArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Titanic",@"Batman",@"Spiderman",@"Avatar",@"Pirates ofcarrrabiean",@"Avengers",@"Harrypotter",@"starwars",@"Lordofrings", nil];
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSArray`. There's a bunch of methods for sorting. Show what you have tried and explain whatever issues you may be having.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *shortedArray=[mutArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```